# fstab doesn't work since upgrade to 14.10

Tags: fstab

the nfs-mount doesn't work automatically since 14.10. When I mount with `sudo mount 192.168.1.50:/data /home/user/Server` everything is ok, but not by fstab.
The line in fstab is ok:

```
192.11.97.2:/data /home/stefan/Server nfs rw 0 0
```

`sudo mount -a` mounts at once. Only after a start there is no mount.
I use gigabit LAN and DHCP just like before the upgrade. Nothing has changed. I wrote the Lines sleep 5 mount -a in rc.local. This workaround works. But I would like to know why this is necessary.
The IP's are only an example I certainly know that they differ.

Comment: Please [edit] to show the broken line in fstab.

Comment: Presumably the network isn't up in time. Are you on Wifi? Using static IPs or DHCP?

Comment: You _did_ realize that the IPs are different, did you?

Comment: Same problem here. Everything was fine on 14.04, but as soon as I upgraded to 14.10 my nfs shares stopped mounting automatically.